# Remove text after a loop

Tags: c#, string

I have a for loop that adds a radiobutton text at the end of a string. Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    sqlQry.Text += listView1.CheckedItems[i].Text + radioButton9.Text;
                }
```

is there a way to trim the `radioButton9.Text` after the loop ends?

Something like:

```
sqlQry.Text = sqlQry.Text.TrimEnd(',');
```

Right now the Result is something like: "A and B and C and"
I want it to be: "A and B and C"
I did try the code i mentioned but i cannot use:

```
sQlQry.Text=sqlQry.Text.TrimEnd(radioButton9.Text);
```

Comment: Yes. that only works for characters.

Comment: did you tried what you asked?

Comment: What about `String.Join` instead of that loop?

Comment: Why not do something like: `string.Join(radioButton9.Text, listView1.CheckedItems)` Looks like @Pikoh beat me to it =)

Comment: I'm sorry @TimSchmelter, but it does compiles.`ListView.CheckedItems` is a collection of `ListViewItem`, and it does have a `Text` property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `string.Join`

```
sqlQry.Text = string.Join(radioButton9.Text, listView1.CheckedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot easier to use a different logic so that you don't put the separator there at the end in the first place.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
   if(i != 0)
   {
      // Put separator in before this thing 
      // when this is not the first thing we add.
      sqlQry.Text += radioButton9.Text;
   }
   sqlQry.Text += listView1.CheckedItems[i].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Length of radioButton9.Text and do a Substring of
 your sqlQry.Text

```
sqlQry.Text.Substring(0, sqlQry.Text.Length - radioButton9.Text.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: [`string.Substring(startIndex, length)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example: `sqlQry.Substring(0, sqlQry.Length - /*fixedLength*/ radioButton9.Text.Length)`

This returns a string which takes off a fixed amount of characters from the end. Updated takes off the length of the radioButton9's text property's length.